# permission denied even as root!

Tags: server, permissions, chmod, chown

recently we had to transfer some files between our servers(both ubuntu server 18.04). apparently the person who did this, didn't use the `-a` option of `rsync`(to preserve ownership information). So now, those files in the new server are owned by `nobody:nogroup`.

Well, I thought this was no problem, I just had to use `chown`. But `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER <directory>` just gives `operation not permitted`. This is already weird, but I logged in as root using `sudo -i` and tried to chang the ownership and the result was the same.

I googled the problem and people were talking about the directory being immutable. But `lsattr -d <directory>` returns `------------------` which means the directory is not immutable. But looking at `ls -ld <directory>` shows that only the owner(`nobody:nogroup`) has write access. So I try `sudo chmod -R 666 <directory>` but I get `operation not permitted` again.

At this point I just wanted to get it over with, so I edited `/etc/passwd` so that I can login using `nobody`. But even as `nobody` I got `operation not permitted`.

So now I have this huge space taken by these files that I can't delete but I also can't use in production.

Any suggestions?
thanks

Comment: `sudo -s` then try again.

Comment: `operation not permitted`

Comment: How is the filesystem on which the directory resides mounted? what is the output of `findmnt -T <directory>`?

Comment: `/      rpool/subvol-6883-disk-0 zfs    rw,noatime,xattr,posixacl`